# How to call public void(int i,string s)

Tags: java, android, string, android-activity, void

I have main activity that it contain public void(string,int) & some where in main activity i would like to call the public void but i get error that 'void checkout(string,int) cannot be applied to ()'...

this is how i call my public void:

```
main activity {
//some where in main activity 

checkout();  //here i call public void but this line show error

public void checkout(String answer,int missedcallcount){

String MissedCallWhere = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE + " AND " + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1";

Cursor cmissedcallc = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,MissedCallWhere, null, null);
cmissedcallc.moveToFirst();
Log.d("CALL", ""+cmissedcallc.getCount()); 
missedcallcount = cmissedcallc.getCount();
cmissedcallc.close();


if (missedcallcount<=5){
     answer= "you have less than 5 miss call";
 }else if (missedcallcount>5){
     answer= "you have more than 5 miss call";
 }

}
}
```

please help me with that...thank you

Comment: `checkout` takes 2 arguments, you are currently not passing any to it.

Comment: Call parameters!

Comment: Please learn how to use Java first   http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

Comment: Indent your code properly if you would like people to try and read it.

Comment: Please follow @Kushan advice here. You are making quite a few mistakes  here that show that you have some fundamental misunderstandings of how java works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void checkout(String answer,int missedcallcount)
```

Declaration of this method shows, that you need to pass two parameters to call it properly - in this example, if you want to call this method you need to pass to it `String` as a first argument, and `int` as a second argument. Here is an example of correct calling this method:

```
checkout("Abcdef", 12345);
```

Comment: thank you...i know that adding string "abcd" and int 123456 will fix the error...but i want the result of my public void...if i use this form -checkout("abcd","1234")- it will replace this parameter to my public void result parameters?? i mean the result will be like this -answer="abcd" or not??? please help me again...and tell me how to learn call void like this -public void dosomething (int i,string s,context ctx)

Comment: @faraz13 I think that you should consider taking some time and studying basic concepts of Java language first, before going into deeper aspects of developing applications for Android devices. You need to understand what returning value from the method means, how assigning values to variables work, how passing the arguments to the method work, what they affect to and what does scope of method mean. If you spend some more time with basic Java concepts, studying for example things that I mentioned here, next steps (for example developing Android apps) will become much easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
checkout();  //here i call public void but this line show error
```

You should call parameters in constructor, in this case code should look like this:

```
checkout(answer, missedCallCount);
```